# Union throwing error

Tags: oracle, join, union

The query included throws an error, help me out understanding it.

```
select name, grade, marks
  from students, grades
  where min_mark<=marks and
        marks <= max_mark and
        marks >= 70
  order by grade desc,name
union 
select to_char('NULL') as name, grade, marks
  from students, grades
  where min_mark<=marks and
        marks <= max_mark and
        marks <=69
  order by grade desc,marks asc;
```

ERROR:

```
union 
* 
ERROR at line 3: 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one `ORDER BY` clause for your whole query, and it comes at the end. Take the one in the middle out.

```
select name, grade, marks
  from students, grades
  where min_mark<=marks and
        marks <= max_mark and
        marks >= 70
union
select to_char('NULL') as name, grade, marks
  from students, grades
  where min_mark<=marks and
        marks <= max_mark and
        marks <=69
  order by grade desc,marks asc;
```

Also since your sets don't seem to overlap, `union all` will give you slightly better performance than `union`.